# jQuery selecting all child checkboxes

Tags: jquery

Firstly, just wanted to say I am hopeless with jQuery.

I was looking at some code from a post on here which selects each parent checkbox (and works):

```
$(function() {
  $(":checkbox").change(function () {
    $(this).parents().children(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
  });
});
```

We have a tree view structure using `<ul> <li>` and each `<li>` has a checkbox.
I want to do the opposite of the above and perform the same checkbox selection on all child checkboxes.

Can anyone modify the above to do that?

Just to note we are using razor and each checkbox is a @Html.CheckboxFor so the output is along the lines of:

```
<input name="Survey.Buildings[0].IsSelected" type="checkbox" value="true" checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Selected? field is required." id="Survey_Buildings_0__IsSelected" />
<input name="Survey.Buildings[0].IsSelected" type="hidden" value="false" />
```

- EDIT 2:

OK I have fixed the HTML and the structure now looks like:

```
<ul>
    <li> Cbx1
        <ul>
            <li> Cbx 2 </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> Cbx3 </li>
    <li> Cbx4   
        <ul>
            <li> Cbx 5 </li>
            <li> Cbx 6 </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So if Cbx4 was checked Cbx5 and 6 would be checked, and if it was unchecked they would be unchecked

Much appreciated

Andy

Comment: You will have to provide some specific HTML snippet, and describe exactly which boxes should be checked when a certain box changes.

Comment: if Cbx2 is checked nothing will happen, I oly want to toggle the child checkboxes. So cbx1 would toggle cbx2 not vice versa, and cbx4 would toggle cbx5 and 6.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[***jsFiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/mU3FV/7/)

```
$(function() {
  $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
    $(this).siblings('ul')
           .find("input[type='checkbox']")
           .prop('checked', this.checked);
  });
});
```

Comment: Problem is that on your jsfiddle example when 3 is selected, 4 is selected and it is not a child of 3. So in the example on my post when Cbx3 is selected nothing else would be affected as it has no child LI's

Comment: I see yes, 5 and 6 should exist in the same LI which is what could be my problem, I will amend my HTML, and would your example work?

Comment: I have updated my post to reflect how the HTML now looks. As you can see CBx5 and CBX6 are now a child list inside the CBX4 list. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  $(":checkbox").change(function () {
    $(this).children(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
  });
});
```

Not really clear with your question but you may try again by removing the parent() as shown above.

Answer (score -1):

My solution is unique and easy

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" class="" onclick="toggleCheckBox(this.id)"> Parent 1 check all
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="choice2" class="chk1"> <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="choice3" class="chk1"> <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="choice_1" class="chk1">
    <br>
    <h1> test 2 </h1>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" class="" onclick="toggleCheckBox(this.id)"> Parent 2 check all
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox"  class="chk2">
    <br>
    <h1> test 3 </h1>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk3" class="" onclick="toggleCheckBox(this.id)"> Parent 3 check all
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox"  class="chk3">
</div>

<script>
        function toggleCheckBox(id) {
            $('#'+id+'').on('change', function() {
                $(this).nextAll('.'+id+'').prop('checked', this.checked);
            });
        }

        //toggleCheckBox('chk1');

</script>
</body>
</html>
```