# Jquery checkbox select all children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML form where I want to check all children after clicking on parent. The parent should be link. So far I managed to do this but the parent contain also checkbox. Here is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/b6AQr/

```
<input type="checkbox" name="rights[]" value="1" class='selectAll' data-checkbox-name='c1' /><strong>Parent 1</strong>
<input type="checkbox" name="rights[]" value="2" class='c1' />Child 1.1
<input type="checkbox" name="rights[]" value="2" class='c1' />Child 1.2

<input type="checkbox" name="rights[]" value="1" class='selectAll' data-checkbox-name='c2' /><strong>Parent 2</strong>
<input type="checkbox" name="rights[]" value="2" class='c2' />Child 2.1
<input type="checkbox" name="rights[]" value="2" class='c2' />Child 2.2
<script>
      $(':checkbox.selectAll').on('click', function(){
        $(':checkbox[class='+ $(this).data('checkbox-name') + ']').prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked")).trigger("change");
      });
</script>
```

So I want to end with parent in anchor. Can someone help me ? Thanks.

Comment: Its not clear what exactly you are asking for...

Comment: I want to change the Parent for `<a class='selectAll'>Parent</a>` and after clicking on this link I want to check all the childs

Comment: you can try my solution :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853568/jquery-selecting-all-child-checkboxes/65407433#65407433

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this too (`nextUntil('a.selectAll')` will select all checkboxs before `a.selectAll`)

```
$('.selectAll').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).nextUntil('a.selectAll').prop('checked', function(){
        return !this.checked;
    });
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/b6AQr/4/)

### Update :

You may try this alternative, notice `data-checkbox-name='c1'` in the `a` tag

**HTML :**

```
<a href="#" class='selectAll' data-checkbox-name='c1'>Parent</a>
<input type="checkbox" name="rights[]" value="2" class='c1' />Child 1.1
<input type="checkbox" name="rights[]" value="2" class='c1' />Child 1.2
```

**JS :**

```
$('.selectAll').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var t = $(this), cls = t.attr('data-checkbox-name');
    $(':checkbox.'+cls).prop('checked', function(){
        return !this.checked;
    });
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/b6AQr/6/)

Comment: I'm bumping my head against wall because it is workin in fidle but not at my project ...

Comment: I dont know where I'm making mistake.. I have that anchor in table tags could it be the problem ?

Comment: Working good just one more think. If there is a child already selected and I click on parent it unselect it. Some condition would do it but I'm totaly new in JS.

Comment: Do you want it to be remain selected ?

Comment: Thanks a lot man for your effort and time just let me know when you make edit I will mark it answer asap

Comment: @DeiForm, check [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/b6AQr/7/), it was a little bit tricky.

Comment: Thanks you are jQuery God :D

Comment: @DeiForm, Welcome and Thanks for the complement :-)

Answer (score 1):

Change the parent to an `<a/>` tag. Simple. I took the liberty of making your HTML semantic, like adding labels for the text next to checkbox, etc. So now I have a structure like this :

```
<div class="set"> 
    <a href="#" class="parent">Parent1</a>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="rights[]" value="2" class='c1' id="c1-1" />
        <label for="c1-1">Child 1.1</label>
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="rights[]" value="2" class='c1' id="c1-2" />
        <label for="c1-2">Child 1.2</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

You'd repeat this for as many times as possible. Note the `for` attributes in the label. Thats also important because when you click on a label, it'll automatically check/uncheck the checkbox corresponding to it. Your click event is below :

```
  $('.set').on('click', ".parent", function () {
      //get the checkboxes from the neighboring <div>
      var $checkboxes = $(this).next().children("[type=checkbox]");
      //check the state of the checkbox (this will give out only the first checkbox, but thats ok for our cause)
      var isChecked = $checkboxes.prop("checked");
      //invert the checked property based on isChecked variable.
      $checkboxes.prop("checked", !isChecked);
  });
```

The reason I've bound it to `.set` is because something called event delegation. Its not important in this question but that makes the code cleaner (in my opinion). The click could also look like this :

```
$(".parent").click(function() { ..
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/b6AQr/1/

Comment: It works like I would like to but is that class set needed ? I am making this in loop and I would have to change it a lil bit

Comment: this solution is better than mine.. you dont need checkbox for selecting other checkboxes

Comment: you can remove it if you want @DeiForm

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replaceWith` function

```
    $(':checkbox.selectAll').on('click', function(){
    $(':checkbox[class='+ $(this).data('checkbox-name') + ']').prop("checked",   $(this).prop("checked")).trigger("change");
      $(this).replaceWith("<a class='selectAll'>"+$(this).text()+"</a>");
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b6AQr/2/