# Select all child checkboxes, checked them and save their value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have nestable list with checkboxes and I need to work that check parent checkbox make all child checked and save children values into array.

I already figure out checking of all child checkboxes, when parent is checked? But I am not able to save their values at the same time.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li class="main-parent">                                 
        <input class="main-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="id">   
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input class="sub-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1">
            </li>
            <li>
                <input class="sub-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2">
            </li>
            <li>
                <input class="sub-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="3">
            </li>
         </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function () {
    var array=[];
    if(type === "main-checkbox") {
        var parent = $(this).closest('.dd-item');

        if('$(parent).find('.sub-checkbox').is(":checked")) {
         array.push($(parent).find('.sub-checkbox').prop('checked',this.checked).val());
        }
    }
});
```

This one return empty array and nothing is saved. Is possible to do it somehow like that?

Comment: you can try my solution :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853568/jquery-selecting-all-child-checkboxes/65407433#65407433 , here i am showing how to select all child checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$(function () {
    $('input:checkbox.main-checkbox').click(function () {
        var array = [];
        var parent = $(this).closest('.main-parent');
        //check or uncheck sub-checkbox
        $(parent).find('.sub-checkbox').prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"))
        //push checked sub-checkbox value to array
        $(parent).find('.sub-checkbox:checked').each(function () {
            array.push($(this).val());
        })
    });
})
```

Answer (score 3):

With **Pure JavaScript**, the approach would be as follows:

1. Use **[querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)** to retrieve the main check-box and add a click listener which runs a function say, `toggleCheck()`.
2. Use **[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** to retrieve all the child check-boxes and assign them to a variable say, `children`.
3. You can then use the **[forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** method to toggle each checkbox inside the `children` variable whenever the main checkbox is click.
4. Finally, add an `if statement` to the function that will push any child checkbox value to your array if it is checked and return it.

---

Check and run the following **Code Snippet** for a practical example of what I described above:

```js
var main = document.querySelector(".main-checkbox");
var children = document.querySelectorAll(".sub-checkbox");

function toggleCheck() {
  var array=[];
  children.forEach(child => {
    child.checked = child.checked == true ? false : true

    if (child.checked == true) {
      array.push(child.value);
    }
  })

  console.log(array);
  return array;
}

main.addEventListener("click", toggleCheck);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="main-parent">                                 
<input class="main-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="id">   
<ul>
  <li><input class="sub-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1"></li>
  <li><input class="sub-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2"></li>
  <li><input class="sub-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="3"></li>
</ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this is not working correctly if i check child and then chcked parent then child is unchecked while parent should check or uncheck with child it should check if child is checked then it stay on checked or uncheck of child should stay uncheck of parent.

Answer (score 1):

The code in this fiddle allows you to check all `.sub-checkbox`-classes by clicking on the `main-checkbox`. All the values are pushed to an array (or erased if unchecked).

https://jsfiddle.net/vs9pb1xu/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.main-checkbox').change(function () {

       var array=[];

        $(this).siblings().find('input').each(function(){
            $(this).trigger('click'); 
            if($('.main-checkbox').is(':checked')){
                array.push($(this).val());
            }
        });
        console.log('>>>'+array);
});
```